# How to invoke parent function from child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying invoke parent component from child component that nested within `<router-outlet>` tag. In my case, I tried to invoke `timer.start()` function that start the timer which lies within parent component.

I have succefully invoked the parent's function by importing to the child, but the timer is not working. I have tried to log the flag that indicated if the timer is running or not, and it's already in `true` condition.

Here is the code:

```
import { NavbarComponent } from './../navbar/navbar.component'; /* This is the parent component */
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-css-inoculation-scoring',
    templateUrl: './css-inoculation-scoring.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./css-inoculation-scoring.component.scss'],
    providers: [ NavbarComponent ]
})

export class CSSInoculationScoringComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _service: DataModelService, private _navbar: NavbarComponent) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.vessel.getVessel();
        this._navbar.timer.start();
    }
}
```

And this is the timer.start function:

```
start: () => {
    this.timer.isTicking = true;
    this.timer.startTime();
}
```

The timer.start function also called another function, here is the timer.startTimer() function:

```
startTime: () => {
    if (this.timer.isTicking) {
      let hour = parseInt(this.timer.hour, 10);
      let minute = parseInt(this.timer.minute, 10);
      let second = parseInt(this.timer.second, 10);

      second += 1;

      if (second > 60) {
        minute += 1;
        second = 0;
      }

      if (minute > 60) {
        hour += 1;
        minute = 0;
      }

      this.timer.second = second < 10 ? `0${second}` : `${second}`;
      this.timer.minute = minute < 10 ? `0${minute}` : `${minute}`;
      this.timer.hour = hour < 10 ? `0${hour}` : `${hour}`;

      setTimeout(this.timer.startTime, 1000);
    }
  }
```

I have idea to change the value of `isTicking` through the service, and return the observable. I have another case similar, and it's work. But in `timer.startTime()` function also modified the properties of timer. Should i also use service for that? Or is there any other approach?

Comment: user http://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Consider using `@Output` in angular.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you want to call parent's method with parent's context.
I would recommend to avoid passing components as services, because if there's a functionality that needs to be shared - it should be a service. But if a child needs to trigger parent's method within parent's context, then you can pass it to a child and call if from there.

```
// child component  
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-css-inoculation-scoring',
  templateUrl: './css-inoculation-scoring.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./css-inoculation-scoring.component.scss'],
})

export class CSSInoculationScoringComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() startTimer: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private _service: DataModelService)

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vessel.getVessel();
    this.startTimer.emit();
  }
}

// PARENT COMPONENT TEMPLATE
<targeting
  (startTimer)="timer.start()">
</targeting>
```

Answer (score 3):

Theres no way a child component can invoke a function on its parent component directly. Using an EventEmitter as per the above example is the closest thing to it. But if your child component is declared as a child route in a routing module, you wont be able to do this (there now way to bind the event emitter).

I would suggest moving your timer logic into a shared service that can be injected into both components. This way you can have either component call the `start` functions as and when they need to.

If you provide this service as a singleton (by providing it only once via your module), you will be able to keep track of whether the timer is running via your `isTicking` flag.